# jQuery / canvas: check if rectangle crosses another rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I have a grid on which users can draw rectangles (actually rooms in a house). Because rooms cannot cross each other, I try to check for conflicts before drawing the second room. So far I managed to check if the 'to-point' of the second rectangle is inside the first rectangle (=> return false). But the code has to 'return: false' also when the boundaries of the room **cross** another room.

[I have set up an example page here](http://www.pixlogic.be/so/)

To try it, click anywhere in the grid and click somewhere else to create the first room. Then click outside this box and move the cursor to see the problem...

In the source code I have marked the concerning code (starts on line 175).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You return false in the anonymous function called by the each statement :-)  the checkConflict function always return true ! Look :

```
function checkConflict(fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
    $.each(rooms, function() {
        var left1 = fromx;
        var left2 = $(this)[0];
        var right1 = tox;
        var right2 = $(this)[2];
        var top1 = fromy;
        var top2 = $(this)[1];
        var bottom1 = toy;
        var bottom2 = $(this)[3];

        if (bottom1 < top2) { return false; }
        if (top1 > bottom2) { return false; }
        if (right1 < left2) { return false; }
        if (left1 > right2) { return false; }
    });  
    return true;
}
```

This is easy to fix but I give you the updated code because your tests are not correct too ( you want to test if you are INSIDE the box, your previous code would always return false ) So this is probably something like this (you have to improve this code because it won't work perfectly either) :

```
  function checkConflict(fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
    var returnValue = true;
    $.each(rooms, function() {
       if (tox > this[0] &&
           tox < this[2] && 
           toy > this[1] && 
           toy < this[3]) 
        { returnValue = false; return false; }

        if (fromx > this[0] && 
            fromx < this[2] &&
            fromy > this[1] && 
            fromy < this[3]) 
        { returnValue = false; return false; }

    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

**EDIT:**
I wrote the correct code. I thought it would be easier but, a promise is a promise...  There are probably ways to refactor the code but the headache is enough for now :-D

I made a JSFiddle so you can see the result : http://jsfiddle.net/T4ta9/2/

```
function checkConflict(fromx, fromy, tox, toy) {
    var returnValue = true;
    $.each(rooms, function() {

         var squareLeft = Math.min( parseInt(this[0]) ,parseInt(this[2])) , 
            squareRight = Math.max(parseInt(this[0]) ,parseInt(this[2]))  , 
            squareTop = Math.min(parseInt(this[1]) ,parseInt(this[3])) ,
            squareBot = Math.max(parseInt(this[1]) ,parseInt(this[3])) ;

         //drawing inside a shape
         if ((fromx > squareLeft && fromx < squareRight && fromy > squareTop && fromy < squareBot) 
         && (tox > squareRight || tox < squareLeft || toy > squareBot || toy < squareTop)) {
        returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }

        // meet the bottom of the current square ?
        if (fromy >= squareBot && // we are below this square 
                ( 
                (toy < squareBot) &&  // and our destination is above the bottom of this square
                    ( 
                        (
                            fromx < squareRight && // we are drawing on the inner left side of this square
                            (tox > squareLeft || fromx > squareLeft)  // and our destination is on the left of this square, or we started to draw on the right part of this square
                        ) 
                        || 
                        (
                            fromx > squareLeft && // we are drawing on the inner right side of this square
                            (tox < squareRight || fromx < squareRight)  // and our destination is on 
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) 
        {
            returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

        // meet the top of a square ?
        if (fromy <= squareTop && 
                ( 
                (toy > squareTop) &&  
                    ( 
                        (
                            fromx < squareRight && 
                            (tox > squareLeft || fromx > squareLeft) 
                        ) 
                        || 
                        (
                            fromx > squareLeft && 
                            (tox < squareRight || fromx < squareRight)  
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) 
        {
            returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

        // meet the left of a square ?
        if (fromx <= squareLeft && 
                ( 
                (tox > squareLeft) &&  
                    ( 
                        (
                            fromy < squareBot && 
                            (toy > squareTop || fromy > squareTop) 
                        ) 
                        || 
                        (
                            fromy > squareTop && 
                            (toy < squareBot || fromy < squareBot)  
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) 
        {
            returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

        // meet the right of a square ?
        if (fromx >= squareRight && 
                ( 
                (tox < squareRight) &&  
                    ( 
                        (
                            fromy < squareBot && 
                            (toy > squareTop || fromy > squareTop) 
                        ) 
                        || 
                        (
                            fromy > squareTop && 
                            (toy < squareBot || fromy < squareBot)  
                        )
                    )
                )
            ) 
        {
            returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }

    });
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: you can also do a `return false` from the inner function whenever a conflict is detected. This way, the loop stop immediately, so the execution time is reduced :)

Comment: also, all the `$(this)[0]`-like statement are not needed. In his code, `this` refer to an array object (it's an element from `rooms` array), so you can directly access to its value by doing `this[0]` instead of `$(this)[0]`: you don't need to create a jQuery object for that. By doing so, you will remove `8 * rooms.length` jQuery objects creation, which is HUGE. I know it's was not part of the question, but to me it make sense to point that out :)

Comment: This does work, but only as long as the mouse doesn't exceed the first rooms' boundaries. I have uploaded a screenshot to illustrate this issue. [link](http://www.pixlogic.be/so/screen.png)

Comment: I'll edit my answer to give you a correct code when I come back home

Comment: You sir, are my hero! That's the solution! I'll now read your code several times so I'll fully understand it :) many many thanks!

Comment: @Nathan I updated the jsfiddle, I didn't consider if you start drawing from inside a shape... Now I did http://jsfiddle.net/T4ta9/2/

Comment: you should set the second parameter (called `radix`) of the `parseInt` method to 10, because you may get some unexpected results. See [MDN page for parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for more information :) /ping @Nathan

Answer (score 0):

This http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/collision-detection-r735 algo looks fairly stealable.

Comment: Hm, I updated the page, problem not solved... Something is still wrong.

Comment: PS: I tested all the variables in the function (console.log) and the variables' results are as expected.